# ymap3-components для Яндекс карт. React + Rypescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, яндекс-карты

Кто-нибудь использовал Clusterer в библиотеке ymap3-components. Никак не выходит. API-ключ в порядке. Обычные маркеры он выводит, а вот кластеры нет, у него возникает проблема с clusterByGrid